# When were Lvalue references introduced in C++?

Tags: c++

When were Lvalue references introduced in C++?

A google search for this question returns for me articles with emphasis on Rvalue references. My question is about Lvalue references (a single &).

In what version of C++ were they introduced?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)

Comment: I have always though references appeared with C++. Isn't it the case?

Comment: @staticx That question is about the semantic difference between rvalues, lvalues, etc. It doesn't ask *when* were any of these types of expressions introduced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

References were present in the first edition of "The C++ Programming Language" in 1985, before the language was standardized.

But they existed since it was renamed from "C with Classes" to "C++" in 1983.

See 3.3 in http://www.stroustrup.com/hopl2.pdf.